# How to not import Vue in main js and store

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have `import Vue` in main.js and also in index.js where I created a Vuex store. How to import Vue only one time? Or it is normal?

Can I import Vuex and Vue only in mainjs and  call that also in main.sj `Vue.use(Vuex)`?

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import store from './store'
import router from './router'
import VueCookies from 'vue-cookies'
import { i18n } from './plugins/i18n'

Vue.use(VueCookies)
Vue.store = store
App.router = Vue.router
App.i18n = i18n
App.store = store

new Vue(App).$mount('#app');
```

and index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import auth from './modules/auth'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    auth
  },
  strict: debug,
});

export default store;
```

Comment: Yes, it normal, else it would be undefined. Dont worry though its cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not imported twice. It is registered in a namespace in such a way, that all the modules (files) importing it, refer to the same module.
Don't worry, it's not imported twice.